# How can I use the .Show() method in such a way the user can't click other forms already opened in background?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, show, showdialog

Now i'm using a'jobdone' flag and the following behaviour (that it looks quite horrible to me...):

```
Dim NewLoginForm As New LoginClass

LoginClass.jobdone = False

NewLoginForm.Show()

While (LoginClass.jobdone = False)

    Application.DoEvents()

End While

NewLoginForm.Close()
```

If I try to use ShowDialog() the behaviour is better but it's a problem to manage all the opening and closing windows (if the forms are many) and I notice that all the background already opened forms close themselves either if one ShowDialog() form is closed...

Thanks

Comment: Forms are either modal or modeless. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want a clear method to open forms and when opened the other buttons in general can't be opened/clicked;
or I need a method to prevent the calling (already opened) forms to be closed when a Modal form is closed

Comment: I'm sorry, English is not my mother tongue, so I can make no sense of what you're saying. I think I'll let someone with better English skills handle it.

Comment: Definitely don't loop around a DoEvents. Definitely do ShowDialog.

Comment: FWIW, I think your code should be `While (NewLoginForm.jobdone = False)` (or simply `While Not NewLoginForm.jobdone`). Anyway, the answer I gave you uses a radically different approach, so unless you can't use it for some reason, it's a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

Ran a quick test and this worked perfectly:

```
Public Sub ForceOpen(ByRef frm As Form)
    frm.Show()
    For Each otherForm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        If otherForm Is frm Then
            AddHandler frm.FormClosing, AddressOf BlockFormClosing
        Else
            otherForm.Enabled = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Public Sub BlockFormClosing(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosingEventArgs)
    e.Cancel = True
End Sub

Public Sub EnableOpenForms()
    For Each frm As Form In Application.OpenForms
        frm.Enabled = True
        RemoveHandler frm.FormClosing, AddressOf BlockFormClosing
    Next
End Sub
```

The calling form will open the stay-open form with `ForceOpen(FormStayOpen)`. When the stay-open form's conditions for allowing the user to close it have been satisfied, have it call `EnableOpenForms()`.